# How to Implement Sum with Substitute in For Loop with Python

Tags: python, sympy

I have the computation of integral with a lot of symbolic variables **x,t,n.**

After I get `g` function in terms of **x,t,n**. I want to do summation with for loop to replace the **n** variable into value.

The command `g.subs({n:c})` is not working. the variable `n` here should be replaced by 1, then 2, then to the range number at the for loop.

In mathematical term, `g` at the last line is the sum of a function `g(x,t)` with `n` from 1 to 10.

Is there a series function from sympy that can replace symbolic variable of `n`? if we have three unknown variable in a function ?

this is my MWE:

```
from sympy import pi, series
#from spb import *
#from mpmath import nsum, inf

import sympy as sm
x = sm.symbols("x")
t = sm.symbols("t")
n = sm.symbols("n", integer=True)

L = 20
f1 = (2/L)*x*sm.sin(n*pi*x/20)
f2 = (2/L)*(20-x)*sm.sin(n*pi*x/20)
sm.pretty_print(sm.integrate(f1,(x,0,10)))
sm.pretty_print(sm.integrate(f2,(x,10,20)))

D = 0.475
g = (f1+f2)*sm.sin(n*pi*x/20)*sm.exp(-(n**2)*(pi**2)*D*t/400)

sm.pretty_print(g)

gn = g.subs({n:1})
sm.pretty_print(gn)

for c in range(10):
    g += g.subs({n:c})
    print(g)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding `g` at each iteration. Effectively, after the first iteration your `g` expression doesn't have any `n` variable. Instead, you must keep `g` intact and use it to substitute your value of `n`, and sum it into another variable:

```py
D = 0.475
g = ((f1+f2)*sm.sin(n*pi*x/20)*sm.exp(-(n**2)*(pi**2)*D*t/400)).nsimplify()
sm.pretty_print(g)
s = 0

for c in range(10):
    s += g.subs({n:c})
    print(s)
```

Comment: Alright, I see how it should be done. Thanks a lot!